# Migrador de código de Base de datos (para cambiar de DBMS)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sqlite

Tengo un código generado por MySQL Workbench, que me gustaría importar en otro DBMS.

La pregunta es: ¿Existe algún migrador de código para cambiar de DBMS, es decir, pasar código MySQL a SQLite, Oracle o Microsoft SQL Server?

He buscado por todos lados pero no encontré nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con respecto a tu pregunta puedes utilizar el siguiente sitio web:

- http://www.sqlines.com/online

Este portal te puede servir para convertir tus de scripts de un motor de base de datos a otro.

Tiene soporte para:

- Oracle
- IBM DB2
- Microsoft SQL Server
- MySQL
- MariaDB
- PostgreSQL
- Sybase
- Informix
- Hive
- Redshift
- Teradata
- Greenplum
- Netezza

Entre otras más.

Si quieres una solución instalada en tu ordenador, también puedes descargarla de este otro enlace: http://www.sqlines.com/download

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias hermano por compartir la gran utilidad :D

Comment: Perfecto! Mil gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro que les sea útil! :D